# Difference in ApiController HTTP status between empty Ok and NoContent

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

An `ApiController` returns the HTTP status 200 and any content given as parameter to `Ok(foo)` is sent. If no parameter is given the status is still 200 but no body is sent.

Some clients expect a body or content when receiving a 200 response. Is there a reason an empty `Ok()` does not translate to HTTP status 204 No Content?? Or should there be no parameter-less version of `Ok()`? What is best/recommended practice?

Comment: Not really a proper answer, but `200 OK` would be appropriate to return from an update via `POST` with either a body containing the updated object, or an empty body (since you have the source of truth anyway). You **could** use `204 No Content` for the second case but it wouldn't necessarily be the most appropriate response

Comment: That is exactly the case I am using 204 for currently as some clients complained that an empty body is no valid XML or JSON for 200.

Comment: Of course, there *should* be a parameter-less version of `Ok()`, as this is perfectly valid within the spec. :) You can also do `Ok(null)` for a 204 which is... unpleasant.

Comment: The spec for [200](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) states that a payload is required. So `Ok(void)` is at least weird.

Comment: @aggsol It states: "though an origin server MAY generate a payload body of zero length"

Comment: @PatrickHofman You are right! How did I miss that! Then I shift blame to the clients :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 200 OK and HTTP 204 NO CONTENT are two entirely difference status codes. I would not want my software to suddenly change status codes, just because my output has a certain value. Okay, both are success codes, but still...

If you want to write this yourself, of course, feel free to do so, but do inform the implementing party of the specific status codes returned.

Comment: So the `Ok()` call with no parameter does not sit wrong with you then? Is there difference between an empty HTTP 200 and HTTP 204?

Comment: They are different in their status code, so that is something that shouldn't change implicitly. Read the HTTP RFC for guidance on when to use what status code.

Comment: You could argue that in some cases `null` (which translated to empty content) is a valid content to return, where an HTTP 204 indicates there is no content whatsoever. But that is getting too subjective IMHO.